# Split the same column of data into multiple columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv data, but the data is focus on the first column. I want to split same column into multiple columns, and the save data in a new csv.
[]is a excel cell

For example, now my data is:

```
[0.0     0.00     0.000  0.00000]   [ ] [ ]
[216.6   -81.88   85.236 12.00000]  [ ] [ ]
[214.4   -77.18   80.538  6.00000]  [ ] [ ]
```

I want to split:

```
[0.0]    [0.00]    [0.000]  [0.00000]
[216.6]  [-81.88]  [85.236] [12.00000]
[214.4]  [-77.18]  [80.538] [6.00000]
```

Now my new data will have a empty column between first column and second column.I try this code but the data will be:

```
[0.0]    [0.00]   [0.000]   [0.00000]
[   ]    [    ]   [     ]   [       ]
[216.6]  [-81.88] [85.236]  [12.00000]
[     ]  [    ]   [      ]  [        ]
[214.4]  [-77.18] [80.538]  [6.00000]
[     ]  [    ]   [      ]  [       ]
```

I have this small code:

```py
import csv
l = []
with open('F:\csv\shortcircuit0707','rt') as f: 
    cr = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
    for column in cr:
        l.append(column) 
with open('F:\csv\shortcircuit0707_1','wt') as f2:
    cw = csv.writer(f2)
    for item in l:
        cw.writerow(item)

    cw.writerows(l)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest using pandas for this type of job. The `read_csv` function will allow you to specify the separator (delimiter) of your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data is not exactly in a CSV (C for **comma**) file, but fields are separated by spaces (or tabs).

You can try adding `delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True` (depending on your actual separator) parameters to `csv.reader`. See [the document of the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Working example:

```py
r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: thank you! My data can be  split .But I still have a question. Now my new data will have a empty column between first column and second column.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to using pandas rather than CSV library
install it by this command in terminal ("pip install pandas")
and use it in code

```
import pandas as pd
my_csv=pd.read_csv("M:\csv\shortcircuit0707.csv",delimiter="\t")
my_csv.to_csv("M:\csv\shortcircuit0707_1.csv)
```

Note delimeter could be "\t" or ";" according to your CSV_file split data

see documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html